# Producing x86 assembly code from a binary executable/C array

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I have a C array that contains binary x86_64 machine code, which I need to convert to assembly code on a Linux machine. I have no problem in converting the C array to a binary executable, but can't find the utility to convert it to asm code.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: that utility is called a disassembler.(if you didn't know)

Comment: linux http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125896/how-to-disassemble-a-binary-executable-in-linux-to-get-the-assembly-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for a **disassembler**. A disassembler takes machine code (either from an executable, or from an object file) and turns it back into human-readable assembly language. If that's what you need, have a look at [this list of disassemblers for Linux](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Disassemblers_and_Decompilers#Linux_Disassemblers).

---

Some disassemblers that aren't listed there:

- *IDA Pro*: Apparently one of the most powerful disassemblers. Probably overkill for your purposes.
- *ndisasm* (accompanies the *nasm* assembler)

Answer (score 2):

You need a disassembler. I personally use NDISASM from the NASM package.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to link to GPL code, you could link to libbfd and have it disassemble the array for you.  Do this if you can't afford to spawn a new process that does it.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer libdisasm http://bastard.sourceforge.net/libdisasm.html, 
but you can always call objdump -D.

From my jitter:

```
#ifdef HAVE_LIBDISASM
# define LINE_SIZE 255`
char line[LINE_SIZE];
int pos = 0;
int insnsize;            /* size of instruction */
x86_insn_t insn;         /* one instruction */

x86_init(opt_none, NULL, NULL);
while ( pos < size ) {
    insnsize = x86_disasm(code, size, 0, pos, &insn);
    if ( insnsize ) {
    x86_format_insn(&insn, line, LINE_SIZE, att_syntax);
    printf("(code+%3x): ", pos);
    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        if ( i < insn.size ) printf(" %02x", insn.bytes[i]);
        else printf("   ");
    }
    printf("%s\n", line);
    pos += insnsize;
    } else {
    printf("Invalid instruction at 0x%x. size=0x%x\n", pos, size);
    pos++;
    }
}
x86_cleanup();
#else
fh = fopen("run-jit.bin", "w");
    fwrite(code,size,1,fh);
    fclose(fh);
    system("objdump -D --target=binary --architecture i386"
#ifdef JIT_CPU_AMD64
           ":x86-64"
#endif
           " run-jit.bin");
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The Standard disassembler on linux is a tool called `objdump` and has a very simple use case:

Lets say we have a simple `hello world` ANSI C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

   printf("Hello world!\n");
   return 0;

}
```

In my file called `hello.c` the above code is what I use. When I compile with `gcc` and get my `hello` executable, we will then use `objdump` to do a quick dump conversion. When using `objdump -D hello` we get the following output:

[objdump output](https://pastebin.com/m0pt4KKe)

`objdump` is very good for quick disassembly of executable portions of a C binary.