# How to convert a .o file back to a .c file in C?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I'm sure there's a way. I'm new to C and my research on this led me nowhere.
Is there a command that can convert a .o file to .c?

Comment: Hi Tony, that isn't easily possible. It's called 'decompilation' and unfortunately it's not a simple process.

Answer (score 5):

Usually you can only determine the *assembly language* for the object file, using a *disassembler*.  Here are a few links to discussion on that topic, e.g., for `objdump`:

- [objdump - GNU Binary Utilities](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html)
- [Disassembling a binary in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125896/disassembling-a-binary-in-linux)
- [Using GCC to produce readable assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289881/using-gcc-to-produce-readable-assembly)
- [Linux Interactive DisAssembler](http://lida.sourceforge.net/)

Reverse-compiling (decompiling) is much harder.  Here are a few links to help:

- [convert executable back to C source code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229802/convert-executable-back-to-c-source-code)
- [Reverse Engineering Resources - Decompilers](http://www.backerstreet.com/decompiler/decompilers.htm)

Comment: Ok great thank you! Ill have a look

Comment: -1: Link-only answers are not seen as good answers on this side.  Answers should be able to stand up on their own without any links which your answer does not.

Comment: The what's a good C decompiler question is deleted >:(

Answer (score -1):

.o file has object code and cannot be converted back to its original .c file having high level code . It is just like the fact that chewed food cannot be converted back to its solid form.

Comment: Bad analogy. It's more like IKEA furniture. With a full understanding of the assembly language (manual), compiled code can be manually rebuilt to perform the same task. It is quite difficult work, and it won't be the exact C code (since compilers do lots of optimizing) but it will be functionally equivalent.