# Source to source transformations with llvm opt

Tags: c, optimization, llvm, llvm-ir, transpiler

I'm compiling the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned int i=atoi(argv[1]);
    unsigned int n=atoi(argv[2]);
    unsigned int r=0;
    unsigned int iter=0;

    while(i<n)
    {
        iter++;
        if (r>0) { i=0; r--; }
        else     { i++;      }
    }
    return iter;
}
```

with

```
$ clang -O3 -c -emit-llvm file.c -o file.bc
$ llvm-dis file.bc -o file.ll
```

And when I inspect the resulting `*.ll` file I'm pleasantly surprised, because the entire code shrinks down to:

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define dso_local i32 @main(i32 %argc, i8** nocapture readonly %argv) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  %arrayidx = getelementptr inbounds i8*, i8** %argv, i64 1
  %0 = load i8*, i8** %arrayidx, align 8, !tbaa !2
  %call.i = tail call i64 @strtol(i8* nocapture nonnull %0, i8** null, i32 10) #2
  %conv.i = trunc i64 %call.i to i32
  %arrayidx1 = getelementptr inbounds i8*, i8** %argv, i64 2
  %1 = load i8*, i8** %arrayidx1, align 8, !tbaa !2
  %call.i12 = tail call i64 @strtol(i8* nocapture nonnull %1, i8** null, i32 10) #2
  %conv.i13 = trunc i64 %call.i12 to i32
  %2 = icmp ugt i32 %conv.i13, %conv.i
  %3 = select i1 %2, i32 %conv.i13, i32 %conv.i
  %4 = sub i32 %3, %conv.i
  ret i32 %4
}
```

Which essentially means: `return (n>i)?(n-i):0`
Is there anyway I can translate optimized bitcode back to C source?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29183452/5218277

Comment: Why were you surprised? `iter` is never used and identical to `i` so `iter` is compiled out, `r > 0` is always `false`, so the whole `if (r>0) { i=0; r--; }` is compiled out. Thus you are left with `i=0; while (i < n) i++; return i;` which is `return (n>i)?(n-i):0`

Comment: @AlexLop. the entire loop was cancelled.

Comment: Yes, sometimes the compilers do a great job. Your loop actually said, let's start incrementing `i` by 1 each loop iteration until it equals `n` ==> `n-i`

Comment: I don't know if there's a tool that can decompile .ll files, but you could try using [Ghidra](https://ghidra-sre.org/) and decompile the final binary instead. If you haven't stripped the symbols, the output should be quite readable.

Comment: @FelixG the link is broken, and google-ing it didn't help. It looks like access to source codeis blocked or something.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom that's strange, the link works perfectly fine for me. Maybe it's blocked in your country, because it's a reverse engineering tool? If you have access to GitHub you can try the [Ghidra repository](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [llvm-cbe](https://github.com/JuliaComputing/llvm-cbe). Maybe it will be suitable for you.

Anyway, llvm-cbe was removed from llvm upstream, due it was not working good as I know :D

Maybe [retdec](https://github.com/avast/retdec) is usable somehow, due it is based on llvm, but not sure.