# Converting AT&T syntax program to intel syntax

Tags: assembly, intel, att

The original code produces the following output: The processor Vendor ID is 'GenuineIntel'
Heres the original code:

```
1.         .section .data
2.   output:
3.         .ascii “The processor Vendor ID is ‘xxxxxxxxxxxx’\n”
4.         .section .text
5.         .globl _start
6.   _start:
7.         movl $0, %eax
8.         cpuid
9.         movl $output, %edi
11.        movl %ebx, 28(%edi)
12.        movl %edx, 32(%edi)
13.        movl %ecx, 36(%edi)
14         movl $4, %eax
15.        movl $1, %ebx
16.        movl $output, %ecx
17.        movl $42, %edx
18.        int $0x80
19.        movl $1, %eax
20.        movl $0, %ebx
21.        int $0x80
```

My conversion into intel executes but doesn't display any output on the screen after the code is assembled :

```
1.        .intel_syntax noprefix
2.         .section        .data
3.    output:
4.         .ascii "The processor Vendor ID is 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'\n"
5.         .section   .text
6.         .globl _start
7.    _start:
8.          mov     eax, 0
9.          cpuid
10.         mov     edi, OFFSET output
11.         mov     [edi+28], ebx
12.         mov     [edi+32], edx
13.         mov     [edi+36], ecx
14.         mov     eax, 4
15.         mov     ebx, 1
16.         mov     ecx, output
17.         mov     edx, 42
18.         int     0x80
19.         mov     eax, 1
20.         mov     ebx, 0
21.         int     0x80
```

Comment: Where and how is `output` defined? You translate line 9 `movl $output, %edi` into `mov edi, OFFSET output`, but on the other hand you translate line 16 `movl $output, %ecx` into `mov ecx, output`. Only one choice can be correct, but without definition it is undecidable which one.

Comment: nvm I just added OFFSET to line 16 of the intel code.

Comment: Just noticed I overlooked that'output' is defined as a label. But another thing that makes me wonder is: where is line 10 in the original code? It goes straight from 9 to 11. Is there missing a line?

Comment: Works here with `mov ecx, OFFSET output`.

Comment: Forgive my semantic error I'd been stuck on this program for quite some time so I wasn't really paying attention to my numbering either way there's no line of code missing...

Comment: @Yeezus: you can use `cat -n` to  prepend line numbers automatically.  Or don't, because then people have to strip them out if they want to copy/paste into an assembler.  If you want to number lines, do it with comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have comments in your code, you can make a good start by assembling, and then disassembling in the other syntax.

It might or might not be easier / less error-prone to then move the comments over, if there are any.  It will probably not be convenient to preserve global symbol names, doing this, but some disassemblers can make use of the symbol table.

Even if you decide to do it manually, you can find out if you made any mistakes by **assembling the AT&T and NASM versions.  If those binaries disassemble to the same code, you're good**.  If not, you should quickly spot the place where they're different.

Comment: Good NASM-syntax disassemblers include Agner Fog's `objconv`.  See my answer on [How to disassemble a binary executable in Linux to get the assembly code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33978857) .  Also, for compiler output, you can have GCC compile to MASM-like syntx in the first place with `gcc -Og -masm=intel -S`  ([How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116))