# Converting llvm IR to NASM assembly

Tags: assembly, llvm, nasm

I am trying to convert a whole bunch of llvm IR code to assembly code that runs on NASM. I am not very familiar assembly or llvm IR. I wonder if there are any transpiler/assembler/tools which can help  me do this or if any such tools are available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LLVM-IR still needs to be compiled.  Do that with `clang -c -O3 -march=native -ffast-math` for example, then disassemble with a NASM-syntax disassembler, for example [Agner Fog's `objconv`](https://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv) which produces output that can be assembled.  [How to disassemble a binary executable in Linux to get the assembly code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125896/how-to-disassemble-a-binary-executable-in-linux-to-get-the-assembly-code/33978857#33978857).

Compile -> disassemble is not great for preserving label and symbol names, though.

If you mean hand-written LLVM-IR into *maintainable* NASM by hand, then I think the ease of porting would depend on whether the number of registers used by the code is less than 16; x86-64 only has 15 general-purpose integer registers not including the stack pointer.

If the LLVM-IR uses more, you'd need to decide which "variables" to spill/reload to/from the stack (and when, if you don't just leave some variables permanently on the stack vs. others permanently in registers).