# how to see the assembly of libc functions in an elf

Tags: binary, system-calls, elf, objdump, readelf

how can i see the assembly of standard c library functions in an elf? for example, i have a binary that i have the source code of this binary and i know that printf is called in main function. i want to see the assembly of printf function in this elf. please notice that i want to see the assembly in elf itself.
i search a lot but i don't find anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compile with

```
~$ gcc -static prog.c
```

while `prog.c` uses the functions you the assembly of.
That will statically link the libraries used to the binary.

Then you can just:

```
~$ objdump --disassemble a.out
```

### EDIT

You can even take a simpler way:
just `objdump` the libc library:

```
~$ objdump --disassemble /usr/lib/libc.so.6 // or whatever the path of libc is
```

Comment: thank you. if i don't do statically linking to libraries can't i? i want to know is there the code of these functions (printf and scanf and ... ) in a binary or not?

Comment: I didn't quite understand. If you want the assembly of it, you can `objdump` the `libc.so.6` itself, as I added in the EDIT. If you want the source code, you can just look for it in the internt, it's open source.

Comment: `ldd a.out` can help find the path to `/lib/libc.so.6` if you're not sure what it is.  Also, highly recommend other objdump options, like `objdump -drwC` to show symbol relocations, and not line-wrap.  C++ demangle won't be relevant for libc, but `-drwC` is just a recipe my fingers remember.  For x86, `-Mintel` is also nice if you don't like AT&T syntax.  Anything in [How to disassemble a binary executable in Linux to get the assembly code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5125896) applies