# Better way than a terminal+objdump to read assembly?

Tags: assembly, disassembly

For example if I'm in `perf report` I can press enter to follow a branch. If a bin was using `-g` some source shows up too.

I don't really need the source but it'd be very convenient if I could follow the jumps. What can I do to make reading assembly easier? Since I'm on linux I ended up running perf and using report to read this

Comment: `objdump -d --visualize-jumps=color` is interesting, although unusable on a large binary as it has so many columns of lines.  Agner Fog's `objconv` disassembler will create branch targets, making it easier to find the tops of loops, example in [How to disassemble a binary executable in Linux to get the assembly code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33978857) .  Other answers show examples of `objdump -d -S` to mix source and asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes thats pretty good. If this is an answer I'd accept it

Comment: IDA, Binary Ninja, Radare2, Hopper (for macOS), Ghidra. All are far better alternatives than `objdump` for reading a disassembly. You can double-click on a jump to reach its target and all show the graph of basic blocks.

Comment: Which is your favorite? Which works on linux? I do have a mac (ARM) so I can try hopper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`objdump -d --visualize-jumps=color` is interesting, although unusable on a large binary as it has so many columns of lines.  In a random smaller binary I had lying around (from testing alignment of 64-bit _Atomic vars in 32-bit mode, in case anyone's curious; this binary was from clang):

**`objdump -drwC -Mintel --visualize-jumps=color`**

```
...
 726:                e8 a5 fd ff ff             call   4d0 <pthread_create@plt>
 72b:                83 c4 10                   add    esp,0x10
 72e:                85 c0                      test   eax,eax
 730:      /-------- 75 62                      jne    794 <main+0xb4>
 732:   /--|-------> c5 f8 57 c0                vxorps xmm0,xmm0,xmm0
 736:   |  |         c5 fb 10 8e 48 e8 ff ff    vmovsd xmm1,QWORD PTR [esi-0x17b8]
 73e:   |  |         66 90                      xchg   ax,ax
 740:   |  |  /----> 31 c0                      xor    eax,eax
 742:   |  |  |      31 d2                      xor    edx,edx
 744:   |  |  |      31 c9                      xor    ecx,ecx
 746:   |  |  |      31 db                      xor    ebx,ebx
 748:   |  |  |      f0 0f c7 8e c0 00 00 00    lock cmpxchg8b QWORD PTR [esi+0xc0]
 750:   |  |  |      c5 f9 6e d0                vmovd  xmm2,eax
 754:   |  |  |      c4 e3 69 22 d2 01          vpinsrd xmm2,xmm2,edx,0x1
 75a:   |  |  |      c5 f9 2e d0                vucomisd xmm2,xmm0
 75e:   |  |  |  /-- 75 02                      jne    762 <main+0x82>
 760:   |  |  +--|-- 7b de                      jnp    740 <main+0x60>
 762:   |  |  |  \-> c5 f9 2e d1                vucomisd xmm2,xmm1
 766:   |  |  |  /-- 75 02                      jne    76a <main+0x8a>
 768:   |  |  \--|-- 7b d6                      jnp    740 <main+0x60>
 76a:   |  |     \-> 83 ec 04                   sub    esp,0x4

...
```

---

[Agner Fog's `objconv` disassembler](https://agner.org/optimize/) makes output that's ready to assemble, including labels on branch targets, making it easier to find the tops of loops. Example output in  *[How to disassemble a binary executable in Linux to get the assembly code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125896/how-to-disassemble-a-binary-executable-in-linux-to-get-the-assembly-code/33978857#33978857)* Other answers show examples of `objdump -d -S` to mix source and asm.

---

Also related: *[How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)*  I usually look at `gcc -O3 ... -S` output instead of assembling into a binary.  Unless I already have a specific binary.  The [Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/) has good tools for finding asm associated with a source line, like a loop body, which works most of the time depending on the debug info generated by compilers.

Comment: Great idea with `-S`. I used that before but I don't think I ever used it with the intention of reading the assembly (without modifying it). I tried objconv and will try the rest of your suggestions

Comment: And BTW, `--visualize-jumps=color` actually is colorized on a terminal to help you track which line is which, but SO code blocks don't support that even if I did copy/paste the ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: Is this functionality available for arm binaries as well? I've tried this flag with `aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump`, but it doesn't seem to output any arrows.

Comment: @NikosMavrogeorgis: Apparently not for AArch64.  It did work for me with arm-none-eabi-objdump from GNU Binutils 2.40, but not the same version of `aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump`.  (On a compiler-generated `.o` with a function that had `b` and `b.hi` instructions.)

Comment: Thank you for checking. I would expect that it's straightforward to replicate the functionality for AArch64 as well, but perhaps nobody took up the task yet.

Comment: @NikosMavrogeorgis: Yes, exactly what I was thinking.  objdump does already need to know which instructions are branches so it can print the absolute target address like `b.hi    24 <fib+0x24>`, but probably the visualization was a recent addition and needs separate per-target code for some reason, which nobody's written yet.